# Не открываются страницы buddypress при ручном вводе url-а

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Есть сайт wordpress с buddypress как одной из частей сайта. url-ы на сайте русские. Сервер nginx. Настроен точно так, как указано в wordpress codex про nginx.

Если перейти на какую-либо группу buddypress, используя пункты меню, кнопки и ссылки на сайте, то всё ок.

Но если скопировать url группы в буфер, а затем вставить в адресную строку в новом окне браузера, то получается ошибка 404 не найдено.

Ссылки выглядят так:

```
site.com/группы/название-группы
```

Все страницы в настройках buddypress установлены как надо.

Где чинить? В nginx? В wordpress? В buddypress?

То же самое происходит со страницами участников и лентой.

Answer (score 1):

1. если это происходит только в одном браузере, то, вероятно, причина — в нём.
2. если происходит в любом браузере, то, возможно, причина в некорректных *http-заголовках*, относящихся к кодировке страницы (в частности, [`content-type`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)): кодировка может передаваться некорректно либо вообще не передаваться.

   а ещё кодировка может задаваться в [*html-теге* `meta`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp). и информация, переданная в *html-тэге* `meta`, понятно, не должна противоречить информации в *http-заголовке* `content-type`.

   и если есть несоответствие (или отсутствие) информации, тогда браузер при передаче url в буфер обмена [перекодирует](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), например, `слово` не в (например) `%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be` (т.е., **из** *utf8*), а в (например) `%f1%eb%ee%e2%ee` (т.е., **из** *cp1251*). соответсвенно, получится в результате совсем не тот *url*, который требуется.